# Compatibility issue between Spring and Junit4?

Tags: spring, junit4

I am a having a hard moment for a few days ago. I hope you could help me.

In a simple HelloWorld Project, trying to have both Spring conf file and any Junit test method.

Problem: If at least one of the method get the tag `@Test`, my Junit test wont run if both Spring-context and Junit4 are added as dependencies in my Maven project. If I remove Spring-context from the dependency, it's working.

Assumptions:
 -> If I want to run any Junit test, I must remove Spring-Context from the POM (and so remove the Spring jar from the project).

-> If I want to run any Spring configuration related thing, I must make sure the class I am testing doesn't detains any method with the tag `@Test` (even if I am creating a main class in that test class).

Please see my following image: [image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the console remains blank, no error message anywhere. Spring context is not loaded, and the Junit test doesn't work neither.

How could I debug such things? Eclipse doesn't show any error log in the Console neither in the Error log tab.. I have no idea how to debug/understand from where comes that problem.

I am using following depencies in the POM: 
     [image: POM SCREENSHOT]

I also tried with last version of SPRING but no change.

## EDIT ---#   By playing with the dependencies, I found out the problem comes when adding any spring library (except spring-core)

Please see a successful running test without spring-aop in dependency.

[image: Screenshot]

And then a test where nothing happens after adding Spring-aop in dependency

[image: Screenshot]

Any Idea?

Comment: Please don't add code as images those are just unreadable. Why would an `@Test` require the `main` method to be run... Running a main isn't the same as running the test.

Comment: Thank you for having a look. Indeed I am not familiar with they way to format message on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Regarding your comment, one is not supposed to prevent the other. We can have both, but yes I did tried only with  @Test method without main, and it's not working if Spring is part of the POM. Even if I am not using it anywhere. (nothing happens, blank console) 

Would you know a way to activate / specific log details in Eclipse, in order to see what's really happening in background when launching the Junit test?

Comment: As stated nothing is preventing that, if that would be the case all those 100000's of Spring based apps with unit/integration tests wouldn't work/be tested. And trust me they are running tests.

Comment: I edited the post, I removed the main method. And a  simple test method remains.

I found out more precisely that the conflict comes from spring-aop (spring -context including it)

I added a screenshot with spring-aop in dependency (nothing happen), and without, and it's working.

what a mystery as you said, everybody should have the same issue if there where something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I fixed the issue.

It's actually a bug Eclipse (ticket opened in 2017 which hasn't been resolved yet coz unable to reproduce the problem).

Java policy were blocking when I tried to either launch a Junit Test (with Spring dependencies) or when trying to open de the debugger.

My OS was corrupted at some point, I formatted and now it's working.